# wordpress insert content before comment_template()

Tags: comments, wordpress

I am trying to inject content into the comment_template() similiar to how you can with comment_form().

For example:

```
<?php
$args = array("comment_notes_before" => myrp_api_ratings_form_table(null, true));
comment_form($args);
?>
```

This will make it so what is returned from the myrp_api_ratings_form_table function will appear before the comment form instead of after the submit button.

Is there any way to do something similiar but using the comment_template() function? I tried looking at the codex with no luck. Also, is there any good links to modifying the output of comment_template() any further?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of actions and filters that is available on the comment_template, you can use them to modify the template, or just build your own template. Here's a list of all the filters and actions available:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#Comment.2C_Trackback.2C_and_Ping_Filters

EDIT:

This thou only changes the data of each comment. If you want to change the display, and structure of the real template, I guess you have to create your own template. But it's not as hard as it sounds, there is a great guide in the codex with some nice examples: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments

Comment: I read this linked page and find nothing similar to what I provided above for example, only how to append things to a specific field before/after it is put into the database. any simple examples without building my own comment theme?